# Converting degree minute second (DMS) columns to decimal degrees in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have a data frame like the below and would like to convert the Latitude and Longitude columns in Degree, Minute, Second format into decimal degrees and want the updated table with other column

any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant code that uses `apply`, `lambda` to process each row of the dataframe and creates a new column `lat_decimal` to contain the result.

```
# Create dataframe
d6 = {'id':['a1','a2','a3'], 
      'lat_deg': [10, 11, 12],
      'lat_min': [15, 30, 45],
      'lat_sec': [10, 20, 30]
    }
df6 = pd.DataFrame( data=d6 )

df6["lat_decimal"] = df6[["lat_deg","lat_min","lat_sec"]].apply(lambda row: row.values[0] + row.values[1]/60 + row.values[2]/3600, axis=1)
```

The resulting dataframe:-

```
   id  lat_deg  lat_min  lat_sec  lat_decimal
0  a1       10       15       10    10.252778
1  a2       11       30       20    11.505556
2  a3       12       45       30    12.758333
```